# Updating Database from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-entry

I have a simple problem, and one I feel should be almost trivial. I have a set of data stored in a Database, and I'm using LinqToSql to read that data. That part is fine.

I want to display those rows on a webpage in ASP.NET (C#), and have the user be able to update existing rows and add new rows at the bottom. This I cannot do.

I'm sure it should almost be a single ASP.NET control with a DataSource property, but I'm not even sure where to start looking. I've tried googling it, but I'm not sure what I should be searching for. I'm not afraid of hard work, but I've been wandering in virtual circles for the best part of two days on this one so far.

Please can someone direct me with some suggestions on what to search for, or some example code?

Comment: You tried doing it with a gridview? That seems the simplest way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) and [LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547113.aspx) web controls.

Comment: +1 Gridview should work for you but if you need more fine control check out listview as well.

Answer (score 2):

please read the following link it may help you i hope

http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-vb

i know it a long long story to read but you will get something from it definately

Comment: From my experience this is the easiest way to make this.

Comment: @ Nick:even i used it quite a few times :)